# Magento 2 Admin How to load State base on Country

Tags: magento2, admin

[image]My Form.php File

```
<?php

namespace Meetanshi\Registration\Block\Adminhtml\Registration\Edit;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config;
use Meetanshi\Registration\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country;

class Form extends Generic
{

    protected $_systemStore;
    protected $regionFactory;
    protected $countryFactory;

    public function __construct(
       Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        Config $wysiwygConfig,
        Registration $options,RegionFactory $regionFactory,Country $countryFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;

        $this->regionFactory = $regionFactory;
        $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }


    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        //$dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        try {
            $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
                ['data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                    'method' => 'post'
                ]
                ]
            );
        }
        catch (\Exception $e){

            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info($e->getMessage());
        }
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('wkgrid_');
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Edit Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
        } else {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Add Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
        }
        $fieldset->addField(
            'title',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'title',
                'label' => __('Title'),
                'id' => 'title',
                'title' => __('Title'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'values' => ["mr"=>'Mr',"ms"=>'Ms',"mrs"=>'Mrs'],
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'firstname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'firstname',
                'label' => __('First Name'),
                'id' => 'firstname',
                'title' => __('First Name'),
                'class' => 'required-entry validate-alpha',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'lastname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'lastname',
                'label' => __('Last Name'),
                'id' => 'lastname',
                'title' => __('Last Name'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'email',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'email',
                'label' => __('Email'),
                'id' => 'email',
                'title' => __('Email'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField('gender', 'radios', array(
            'label'     => __('Radios'),
            'name'      => 'gender',
            'values' => array(
                array('value'=>'male','label'=>'Male'),
                array('value'=>'female','label'=>'Female'),
            ),
            'disabled' => false,
            'readonly' => false

        ));
        $fieldset->addField(
            'dob',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'dob',
                'label' => __('DOB'),
                //'date_format' => $dateFormat,
                'date_format' => 'd-MM-y',
                'class' => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'style' => 'width:200px',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'address',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'address',
                'label' => __('Address'),
                'id' => 'address',
                'title' => __('address'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'address2',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'address2',
                'label' => __(''),
                'id' => 'address2',
                'title' => __('address2'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'city',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'city',
                'label' => __('City'),
                'id' => 'city',
                'title' => __('city'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'zip',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'zip',
                'label' => __('Zip'),
                'id' => 'zip',
                'title' => __('Zip'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $countries = $this->countryFactory->toOptionArray();
        $countryData = $fieldset->addField(
            'country',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'country',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'title' => __('Country'),
                'label' => __('Country'),
                'value' => $form['country'],
                'values' => $countries
            ]
        );

        $regionCollection = $this->regionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addCountryFilter($form['country']);
        $regions = $regionCollection->toOptionArray();

        $fieldset->addField(
            'state',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'state',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'title' => __('State'),
                'label' => __('State'),
                'values' =>  $regions,
                'value' => $form['state'],
            ]
        );
        $countryData->setAfterElementHtml("   
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    require([
                    'jquery',
                    'mage/template',
                    'jquery/ui',
                    'mage/translate'
                ],
                function($, mageTemplate) {

                   $('#edit_form').on('change', '#country_id', function(event){

                        $.ajax({
                               url : '". $this->getUrl('*/*/regionlist') . "country/' +  $('#country_id').val(),
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: 'json',
                               showLoader:true,
                               success: function(data){
                                    $('#region_id').empty();
                                    $('#region_id').append(data.htmlconent);
                               }
                            });
                   })
                }

            );
            </script>"
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'phone_no',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'phone_no',
                'label' => __('Phone No'),
                'id' => 'phone_no',
                'title' => __('phone_no'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

On Change ajex not working

Comment: Hi @arjun welcome to magento.stackexchange.com could you please share more details when posting the question so that other developers can understand easily and provide you a quick solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your block file code

```
protected $_countryFactory;

public function __construct(
..............................
\Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $countryFactory,
..............................
) {
..............................
$this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
..............................
}

protected function _prepareForm()
{
    // get region value from Modal
     if ($model->getId()) {
        $region_value = $model->getData('region');
    } else {
        $region_value = NULL;
    }
.....................................................
.....................................................
.....................................................
 $optionsc=$this->_countryFactory->toOptionArray();

    $country =  $fieldset->addField(
        'country',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'country',
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'id' => 'country',
            'title' => __('Country'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'values' => $optionsc,
            'required'  => true,
        ]
    );


    $fieldset->addField(
        'region',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'region',
            'label' => __('Region'),
            'id' => 'region',
            'title' => __('Region'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'values' =>['--Please Select Country--'],
            'required'  => true,
        ]
    );

/* for add java script for country and region select */

    $country->setAfterElementHtml("   

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($) {

                // on intial check whether country code exit or not 

               $(window).on('load', function() {

                var country = $('#storelocation_country').val();
                //var region = $('#storelocation_region').val();

                var region = '".$region_value."';



                    //alert('region '+region+' country '+country);

                    $.ajax({
                           url : '". $this->getUrl('*/*/regionlist') . "country/' + $('#storelocation_country').val()+'/region/'+region,
                           type: 'get',
                           dataType: 'json',
                           showLoader:true,
                           success: function(data){
                                $('#storelocation_region').empty();
                                $('#storelocation_region').append(data.htmlconent);
                           }
                        });



                });   

                // onchange country this function called 

               $(document).on('change', '#storelocation_country', function(event){

                var country = $('#storelocation_country').val();

                //alert(country);

                    $.ajax({
                           url : '". $this->getUrl('*/*/regionlist') . "country/' + $('#storelocation_country').val(),
                           type: 'get',
                           dataType: 'json',
                           showLoader:true,
                           success: function(data){
                                $('#storelocation_region').empty();
                                $('#storelocation_region').append(data.htmlconent);
                           }
                        });
               })
            }

        );
        </script>"
    );
    .....................................................
    .....................................................
    .....................................................
}
```

Now ajax return your option

***Regionlist.php***

```
<?php


namespace [vendor_name]\[Module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\Storelocator;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Regionlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $_countryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {


        $countrycode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('country');

        $regioncode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');

        if($regioncode == NULL){
            $regioncode='';
        }
        //echo " ".$countrycode." ".$regioncode;
        $selected = '';

        $state = "<option value=''>--Please Select--</option>";
        if ($countrycode != '') {
            $statearray =$this->_countryFactory->create()->setId(
                    $countrycode
                )->getLoadedRegionCollection()->toOptionArray();
            foreach ($statearray as $_state) {
                if($_state['value']){

                        if($regioncode == $_state['label']) { $selected = 'selected'; } else{  $selected = ''; }

                    $state .= "<option value='".$_state['label']."'  ".$selected." >" .$_state['label']. "</option>";
            }
           }
        }
       $result['htmlconent']=$state;
         $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
    }

  }
```

***I Hope this helps you***

Comment: Have tried your solution, but the region's list doesn't change when I select a country. It doesn't offer any option. Don't see any errors in the logs, nor anything apart from this going wrong. Any suggestion on what I might have missed, linking some parts together or something?

Comment: please share your code . i will be help you to solve this.

Comment: Hi Please help me to solve this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/346942/magento-directory-country-region-name-table-for-city-city-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

After making some efforts,i found mistake in id of country field and region(State) field,
Thanks For Support!