# Magento directory_country_region_name table for city : City Dropdown

Tags: magento2, custom-options, shipping-address, billing-address, checkout-page

I want to make the country, state, city dropdown in the checkout field. I research lots of times in the internet and I didn't find any solution rather than a paid module. I noticed that for some countries magneto showing state dropdown for others it is a text field only. For example countries like the United States, India then in checkout magneto showing state dropdown, at last, I found where it is coming from.

There are two table in magento

1. **directory_country_region_name**
2. **directory_country_region**

So based on the current structure i am successfully add state drop down to another countries and now its working fine . But i can't understand how can i make city dropdown . Please help . What i am looking is Dropdown city in shipping address field.

> NOTES

***Those who are looking for state dropdown its easy to make*** . You can add values **directory_country_region_name**  with locale, name . After that you will get region_id. Using that region_id you can fill **directory_country_region** . Once you finished that then your textbox for corresponding states are replaced by dropdown with given values. Please check that 2 table closely then you will understand

Answer (score 3):

You need to customize your checkout page layout processor. Try the below codes for creating a new module to customize the checkout page fields:

Step 1:

Create a registration.php file for your module:

> File path: app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::Register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyVendor_MyModule',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 2:

Create a module.xml file for your module:

> File path: app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyVendor_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Step 3:

Declare a plugin for the checkout layout processor.

> File path: app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="customised_layout_processor" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
    
</config>
```

Step 4:

Create plugin class:

> File path: app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Plugin/LayoutProcessor

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use function PHPUnit\Framework\assertIsCallable;

class LayoutProcessor
{

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        //For shipping form
        $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['city'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'drop-down',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.city',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 70,
            'id' => 'drop-down',
            'options' => $this->getCitiesDropdown()
        ];

        //For Billing Form
        foreach ($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                 ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {
            if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['city'])) {
                $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                ['city'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                        'id' => 'drop-down',
                    ],
                    'label' => __('City'),
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'sortOrder' => 70,
                    'id' => 'drop-down',
                    'options' => $this->getCitiesDropdown()
                ];
            }
        }

        return $result;

    }

    public function getCitiesDropdown()
    {
        return [['value' => "test1", "label" => "Test city 1", "is_default" => true], ['value' => "test2", "label" => "Test city 2", "is_default" => true]];
    }

}
```

Step 5:

Run the below commands:

> bin/magento module:enable MyVendor_MyModule

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

> bin/magento s:d:c

> bin/magento cache:flush

After following these 5 steps your module will get enable. Now you can check your checkout page for output:

You will get the results like the below screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Hope it will help you!

Comment: @abilasher Yes, you can create a new module for it. Regarding the second command, yes you are right. The path should be like VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\LayoutProcessor. Still, if you have any doubts, please post it. Let me try to solve your doubts.

Comment: @abilasher I hope you are not aware of module creation. Please check the updated answer and follow the steps. You will get your output.

Comment: Please let me know what options you want to display in the city dropdown?

Comment: Hi you are right. Code is working.  getCitiesDropdown function how i can i get region id & country id

Comment: Give me sometime. Let me prepare code and will post it soon.

Comment: Still didn't work on your code. Let me update it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

For The city dropdown, I believe the solution mentioned in this link will help you.

[How to change City field to a dropdown in Checkout step Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/237219/71417)

Other than that, there are few free modules also available over the git, which you can use for reference or modify as per your need, a few are

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager

https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

Comment: no these solutions want help. Please see my previous comments.